# Fastest way to read binary file with 2d array with fixed number of columns but unknown rows

Tags: python

I have a binary files that has saved values of a 2d array.
All values are saved in double format (8bytes)
The data is written to the file row by row.
I want to read the file as fast as possible without knowing how many rows the file has.

I am doing it this way, but I was wondering if there is a faster method than this:

```
with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(8)
    while byte != "":
        # Do stuff with byte.
        byte = f.read(8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
    for i in f:
        #i is now your line, this only gathers it once.
```

btw your code is faulty the reasong your asking for it to be faster is because you stuck your self in a infinity loop when the line is empty you will get " "*8 not "" because you asked it to read the first 8